# Concatenate a string with a variable in grep command

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep, aix

I have to search by this pattern:

`_20181106`

20181106 is yesterdays date, so it has to be be a variable like

`TZ=aaa24 date +%Y%m%d`

How can I search a file with this pattern?

I'm working with AIX

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **;-)** Could you [edit] your question and provide a bit more info on your use case?  Do you just want to have the value of `_YYYYMMDD` in a variable where `DD` is yesterday?

Answer (score 3):

On AIX, using `/bin/ksh93`:

```
grep "_$(printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' yesterday)" filename
```

Or:

```
grep "$(printf '_%(%Y%m%d)T' yesterday)" filename
```

or:

```
yesterday=$(printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' yesterday)
grep "_$yesterday" filename
```

Note that

```
TZ=aaa24 date
```

will give the date 24 hours earlier from the UTC date, so is only valid to give you yesterday's date where the local time follows UTC (though it may give you the right date at some hours of the day in other time zones).

Comment: this may be a stupid remark, because I don't have any AIX to test on, but shouldn't that be `printf "%(%Y%m%d)T" yesterday` (with a `T` at the end of the format)? trying it without will just print `_%`.

Comment: /bin/ksh and /bin/ksh93 are still separate binaries as of today; /bin/ksh reports `Version M-11/16/88f` and /bin/ksh93 reports `Version M 93t+ 2009-05-01` (AIX 7.2)

Comment: @JeffSchaller. Thanks. Makes sense given that ksh93 is not fully backward compatible with ksh88.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what that 'aaa24' is in your question, but this might help you:

Use command substitution to evaluate the `date` command before running grep.

```
grep $(date +%Y%m%d) foo
```

Comment: AFAIU, it needs to be yesterday's date, not today's...

Comment: `aaa24` is the specification of a timezone that is 24 hours behind UTC (and are labelled `aaa`), so it gives yesterday's date in timezones that use UTC time (I'm not sure what places on Earth use UTC time all year round though).